# Programmatically download dependencies in custom gradle task

Tags: groovy, gradle

I want to create task which depends on few maven libraries. Is it possible to download those libraries from groovy code? What I want to do is to put this code

```
configurations {
    sshexecAntTask
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    sshexecAntTask 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.0'
}
```

Which I use in this way:

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'sshexec', classname: 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec', classpath: project.configurations.sshexecAntTask.asPath)
ant.sshexec(host: host, username: username, password: password, command: command, trust: 'true', failonerror: 'true')
```

Into my `DefaultTask` class. Is it possible?
It should look similar to this:

```
class MyCustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    public MyCustomTask() {
        super()
        // set and download dependencies here
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

I've found that I can do it in this way:

```
project.getRepositories().mavenLocal()
project.getConfigurations().create('sshexecAntTask')
project.getDependencies().add('sshexecAntTask', 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.0')
project.getConfigurations().getByName('sshexecAntTask').resolve()
println('project.configurations.sshexecAntTask.asPath: '+project.getConfigurations().getByName('sshexecAntTask').getAsPath());
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically do something along the lines of:

- `MyCustomTask` lives in its own build (possibly `buildSrc`).
- The `MyCustomTask` project declares `ant-jsch` as a compile dependency.
- The task's action (not constructor) defines (`taskdef`) and executes the Ant task. (Might have to be wrapped with `project.ant.execute { ... }`.)
- Builds that wish to use `MyCustomTask` declare a *build script dependency* on its module (not necessary in case of `buildSrc`). Transitive dependency management automatically brings in `ant-jsch` along with it.

The `customPlugin` sample in the full Gradle distribution is a good place to get started. (Just declare a `compile` instead of a `testCompile` dependency.)

Comment: Tkanks. I forgot that I should add dependencies to build.gradle. After adding an entry `compile 'org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:1.7.0'` it started to work. Tkanks again!